# Convert single column to multiple rows with similar prefixes

Tags: unix

consider i have a file with below content

```
schem1.table1
schem1.table2
schem1.table3
schem2.table4
schem2.table5
schem2.table6
schem3.table7
schem3.table8
```

is it possible to have like below?

```
schem1.table1 schem2.table4 schem3.table7
schem1.table2 schem2.table5 schem3.table8
schem1.table3 schem2.table6
```

there will more than3  schmeas and different tables. .also need them in a tab separated columns in one single file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some form of scripting language for this task.

AWK, GAWK in particular, would be quite easy, but any other language you're familiar with would also work.

A rough algorithm would be to read each line, split it, and for each unique schema create a multi-dimensional array of tables, adding the line to the appropriate position in the array; then at the end of the input file loop across the schema arrays, printing each table in a row, and repeat until the longest array of tables is all printed.

If the input file is very very large and you wouldn't be able to read it all into memory at once, then you could first split it into separate files, one for each schema; then read each line from each file and print the values across in a row, again continuing until the longest file is ended.

Comment: can youplease provide high level code to start with ?